# How do I autofill form data on an external web page?

Tags: php, forms, autofill

I'm putting a link on our site to an external page that contains a generic login for our people.  I would like those login fields to prepopulate using url parameters.  Is this possible?

http://www.ucdir.com/schedule/login.php?username=abcde&password=12345

is what I'm trying but it's not working.

Comment: I'm glad it's not working. Passing plain text passwords via GET would have terrible consequences.

Comment: @Philip The attempt is shown in the question already

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: @Philip Welcome to Stack Overflow - read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your HTML

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?= $_GET['username'] ?>" />
<input type="text" name="password" value="<?= $_GET['password'] ?>" />
```

Comment: Yes. I thought yours is a PHP page considering the login.php in the question.

Comment: Right, sorry, I didn't read the question well enough. Do update your answer though...